# Load Rss Feed from url

Tags: c#, rss

Have some problems while loading XMLDocument. When I try to load [url](https://keddr.com/category/novosti1/) it throws exception:

> *"System.Xml.XmlException: 'Ссылка на необъявленный объект подстановки "raquo"*".

What`s wrong?

C# code:

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
rssXmlDoc.Load(sourceUrl);

XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");

foreach (XmlNode item in rssNodes)
{
    XmlNode rssSubNodeTitle = item.SelectSingleNode("title");
    string title = rssSubNodeTitle != null ? rssSubNodeTitle.InnerText : "";
    Console.WriteLine(title);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a few changes to your code and providing the correct URL RSS you can have these results:

```
String url = "https://keddr.com/feed/";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(url);
SyndicationFeed feed = SyndicationFeed.Load(reader);
reader.Close();

foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: " + item.Title.Text);
    Console.WriteLine("Publish Date:" + item.PublishDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    Console.WriteLine("Link: " + item.Links[0].GetAbsoluteUri().ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(item.Summary.Text");
}
```

I'll show here only the first result, but, you'll get the idea:

```
Title: Собираем новый ПК – выпуск 1
Publish Date:  07/05/2017 17:10:10
Link: https://keddr.com/2017/07/sobiraem-novyiy-pk-vyipusk-1/
// This is the body of the feed:
А вот и новый многосерийный проект на Кеддре! На этот раз мы сняли САМУЮ геморную [&#8230;]
```